# Coldfusion 8 - SerializeJSON not serializing

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfc

I been developing a site offline on a WAMP setup and have been serializing beans using the SerializeJSON function like so:

```
propertyImageBean = CreateObject("component","cfcs.beans.property_image").init();
propertyImageBean.setname("test");
propertyImageBean.setalt("test alt");

<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(propertyImageBean)#</cfoutput>
```

This has all been working correctly and the code above produces:

```
{"name":"test","alt":"asdasd","id":""}
```

However, when I upload my files to the live site the response is just an empty object:

```
{}
```

The local version is running on CF9 and the prod version is on CF8, so this is probably what the issue is.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
<cfscript>

    propertyImageBean = CreateObject("component","cfcs.beans.property_image").init();
    propertyImageBean.setid(1);
    propertyImageBean.setname("test");
    propertyImageBean.setalt("asdasd");

</cfscript>
<cfdump var=#propertyImageBean#>
<cfoutput>id: #propertyImageBean.getid()#</cfoutput>
<cfoutput>alt: #propertyImageBean.getalt()#</cfoutput>
<cfoutput>name: #propertyImageBean.getname()#</cfoutput>
```

Outputs (prod server(:

- A dump of the bean but does not display the bean properties in the dump whereas on the local server it does

  id: 1 alt: asdasd name: test

So it looks like it is a problem with the bean, unless there is a config issue on the server.

CFC:

```
<!--- PROPERTIES FOR DOCUMENTATION PURPOSES ONLY --->
<cfproperty name="id" displayname="id" hint="id of the property_image" type="any" required="True" />
<cfproperty name="name" displayname="name" hint="name of the property_image" type="any" required="True" />
<cfproperty name="alt" displayname="alt" hint="alt of the property_image" type="any" required="True" />

<!--- PSEUDO-CONSTRUCTOR: SETS DEFAULT VALUES IF INIT METHOD IS NOT CALLED --->
<cfscript>
    variables.id = "";
    variables.name = "";
    variables.alt = "";
</cfscript>

<!--- CONSTRUCTOR: TAKES IN ARGUMENTS AND CALLS SETTER (MUTATOR) FOR EACH ATTRIBUTE OF THE BEAN --->
<cffunction name="init" displayname="Init" hint="Constructor for the CFC" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
    <!--- ARGUMENTS FOR THE CONSTRUCTOR, ALL OF WHICH ARE OPTIONAL (NO-ARG CONSTRUCTOR) --->
    <cfargument name="aid" displayname="id" hint="id of the property_image" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="aname" displayname="name" hint="name of the property_image" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <cfargument name="aalt" displayname="alt" hint="alt of the property_image" type="any" required="false" default="" />
    <!--- CALL THE SETTERS (MUTATORS) FOR EACH OF THE property_image ATTRIBUTES AND PASS IN THE ARGUMENTS --->
    <cfscript>
        setid(arguments.aid);
        setname(arguments.aname);
        setalt(arguments.aalt);
    </cfscript>

    <cfreturn this />
</cffunction>

<!--- GETTERS AND SETTERS (MUTATORS AND ACCESSORS) --->
<cffunction name="getid" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn variables.id />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="setid" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="aid" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset variables.id = arguments.aid />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="getname" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn variables.name />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="setname" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="aname" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset variables.name = arguments.aname />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="getalt" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfreturn variables.alt />
</cffunction>
<cffunction name="setalt" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="aalt" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfset variables.alt = arguments.aalt />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: First I'd check if their version of CF8 is the same as your CF8 by dumping the `Server` scope.

Comment: Thanks for your response Henry, I will check this. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Ok, been a bit silly here, my local version is CF9 and the prod version is CF8. This may well be the culprit. Not sure what I should do now though, construct my own JSON string perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, setup CF8 locally. http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#cf8proddl

I guess `SerializeJSON(cfc)` is something new in CF9 that's not available in CF8.  This is not an official, documented feature of `SerializeJSON` I don't believe.

Implement a `getMemento()` function that returns the variables in as a struct, then you can SerializeJSON on that struct.

```
/** a public function in Obj.CFC */
function getMemento()
{
    return {
        x=variables.x,
        y=variables.y
    };
}

// outside of the cfc...
obj = createComponent("component","Obj").init();
objJson = serializeJSON(obj.getMemento());
```

Comment: thanks Henry that worked a treat! Will install CF8 now and prevent myself some confusion!

Answer (score 1):

I'd check to see if it's a problem with serializeJson() or with the CFC's methods.  Check to make sure the values are actually getting set: does getName() and getAlt() return what you'd expect?

Is there a chance that in a production environment there is an issue with simultaneous requests unexpectedly re-initing that CFC instance?

Can you make an entirely stand-alone CFM & CFC which are both pared down to the absolute minimum number of "moving parts" to demonstrate this problem, and still replicate it on both dev & prod?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response. THis is indeed a paired down test case with just the code you see above in a separate CFM. It looks like it's not a problem with SerializeJSON() but with the CFC as the CFC properties are being set and are accessible via the getters but they are not shown when I use cfdump on the bean. I've edited my post above to show you what I mean.